# How to get typed parameters from subclass

Tags: scala

```
trait Binding[InternalType, ExternalType]
object BooleanBinding extends Binding[Boolean, String]
class Field(val binding : Binding[_,_], val name : String)
val field = new Field(BooleanBinding, "name")
```

Given field, how to get InternalType of Binding which in this case is Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the types through reflection. TypeTag is necessary because of type erasure.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Binding[InternalType, ExternalType]

object BooleanBinding extends Binding[Boolean, String]

class Field[A:TypeTag, B:TypeTag](val binding : Binding[A,B], val name : String) {
  val InternalType = typeOf[A]
  val ExternalType = typeOf[B]
}

private val name = new Field(BooleanBinding, "name")

println(name.InternalType)
// Boolean

println(name.ExternalType)
// String
```

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks for your answer. This is working perfectly. Although I oversimplified the original prob
Instead of the Field object, I am actually getting a BaseField object  which is a trait. I'll edit my question to reflect the same.